# Ошибка при разыменовании кортежа в Python. SyntaxError: can't use starred expression here

Tags: python

Приветстсвую! Простенькая конструкция, а-ля питоновский свап не работает...

```
res = (1, 2)
a, b = *res
```

Подскажите, что может быть не так? Ошибка следующая: `SyntaxError: can't use starred expression here`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Для распаковки кортежа не нужна звездочка справа от присваивания

```
a, b = res
```